# How to convert the time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dr["TelaCastTime"].ToString() = 24:25:30 . For that It's not convert into DateTime and showing error. How can i handle it when time 24:25:30  will come?

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TelaCastDate"].ToString() +""+dr["TelaCastTime"].ToString())'
```

Comment: You are concatting an empty string. Shouldn't that be a space?

Comment: What is `24:25:30` supposed to represent? One day, twenty-five minutes and thirty seconds? Something else?

Comment: I believe you meant 0:25:30, right?

Comment: What error is it showing?

Comment: Yes One day, twenty-five minutes and thirty seconds?– Frédéric Hamidi

Comment: @Engr.Suzan So if TelaCastDate is "11-15-2016" and TelaCastTime is "24:25:30" then you want the result to be "11-16-2016 00:25:30"?  Also would you similarly need to handle a time like "48:00:00" that basically adds 2 days to the given date?

Comment: What is the type of dr["TelaCastTime"]? Is it a DateTime object?

Comment: No. Varchar type object.

Comment: @Engr.Suzan did none of the answers work for you? because you haven't accepted any. If you don't know how to do this, then [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help

Answer (score 1):

I changed the whole answer to this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TelaCastDate"].ToString());

string[] s1 = dr["TelaCastTime"].ToString().Split(':');

TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(s1[0]), Convert.ToInt32(s1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(s1[2]));

DateTime yourFinalDateTime = dt.Add(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input you get is really that mangled you may try the below code. It will correct simple numerical errors but throw if the input contains something else than just num:num:num

```
string[] splits = dr["TelaCastTime"].ToString().Split(':');
int[] nums = splits.Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
TimeSpan dt = new TimeSpan(nums[0]%24, nums[1] %60, nums[2] %60);
```

Comment: Error showing:System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: using System.Linq

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# fiddle that works with your input:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VO3QPz

As mentionned in other answer I replace `24` for hours with `00`, then no problem to use `DateTime.TryParse`

```
    var time = "24:25:30";
    var date = "1/1/2001";
    DateTime parsed = new DateTime();

    if(time.StartsWith("24")){
        time = "00" + time.Substring(2);

    }

    DateTime.TryParse(date + " " + time, out parsed);


    Console.WriteLine(parsed);
```

Comment: You should post your code in the answer even if you have a link to it.

Comment: if i want to add second with this time how can i do it?

Comment: and what if it starts with 25?

Comment: @NicoRiff, true I just guessed that the format was 1-24 instead of 0-23, the object seems to come with a date so I doubt the Time is a TimeSpan that can exceed 24 hours.

Comment: @Engr.Suzan what do you mean by add seconds ? you can then use: `parsed.AddSeconds(30);` for example

Comment: @Engr.Suzan then accept the answer for posterity and community :)

Answer (score -1):

i guess the solution you need is something like this

`string Time = "17:08:23";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Time,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
string t = date.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");`

Tell me if it's ok

Comment: If i use,string Time = "24:08:23";
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Time,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); 
string t = date.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"); It;s showing error: he DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: Of course, you have to replace 24, by 00, there is no more than 24 hours .. It seems logical, isn't it ?